# start activity even when phone is locked

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I would like to start an activity like the one used when an alarm starts ringing and a dialog dismiss appears even when the phone is locked and I am able to click it. I have this code from this site but I don't know how to call it when I extend using broadcastreceiver. It always says

> the method `getWindow()` is undefined type for...

I always seemed to get this error everytime I code, what does that mean.

```
public void unlockScreen() {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register boradcast reciever for **SCREEEN_ON intent**.
As screen gets on your braodcast reciever onRecieve(..) will execute, Start your actitvity with flags as you have written in your post in onRecieve method.